# Deep link is opening in Safari browser instead of in the app when using iOS simulator

Tags: javascript, ios, ios-simulator, deep-linking, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a deep link which on real iOS device opens associated iOS app when clicked, as expected, but on simulator it opens link in Safari browser instead of in the app.

We have hybrid app (wrapper around WebView).

Any way to open deep link with the app using simulator?